# Most efficient way to stream list of data to csv

Tags: python, performance

What is the most efficient way to stream data into csv format.  Basically converting a list of data, to csv and support RFC 4180, where strings with " becomes "" and wrapped with quotes.

For example data:

```
[13321,'John','Doe','This "is" it']
```

Will be converted to

```
13321,John,Doe,"This ""is"" it"
```

In short, I am taking a stream of data, and streaming it to csv format and would like to support RFC 4180 standard.

Currently I am doing something like:

```
def to_csv(data):
    converted_data = convert_data(data)
    print(os.linesep + ",".join(converted_data ))

def convert_data(data):
    converted_data = [f"\"{helper(val)}\"" if "\"" in val else val for val in data]
    return converted_data 

def helper(val):
    return val.replace("\"", "\"\"")
```

Where `to_csv` is called per line of data

Comment: maybe open a csv file and append data to it instead? You can easily append to files and keep them open.

Comment: I mentioned streaming since I dont want to save anything in memory, especially since I am streaming tens of GB of data

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer has an example that you can use. Don't reinvent the wheel unless you _really need to!_